# Mac Excel 2008: Macros?

Tags: macos

I know this isn't directly programming related, but at the same time...

Mac Excel 2008 doesn't support VBA or Macros... which I need for a class...

Does anybody know of a solution?  I need a way to write simple macros on Mac in Excel-- if it's possible.

*Please don't give vague answers if you don't know for sure.* This is a serious question. :)

Comment: you are SOL on the Macro front.

Comment: That's what I'm finding out! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to write proper macros, you're SOL with 2008 and would be better off finding a copy of 2004 or Office for Windows. If you just need to write code to control the app, Microsoft's suggested replacement for macros in Mac Office is the native Applescript.

Comment: I'm assuming that Applescript is essentially a different language compared to VBA?

This class is VBA-specific...

Comment: Yeah, Applescript is quite different from VBA. There's no VBA support at all in Excel 2008, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you're into archeology, Mac Excel 2008 supports XLM macros (a.k.a Excel 4.0 macros). You'll have a hard time finding relevant documentation about XLM, as it appears to have gone out of fashion many years ago.
You can create a sheet macro through the "insert sheet" wizard (there's a Excel 4.0 Macro Sheet option).

Then you can download the docs from Microsoft: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=00d31943-3ad1-4df1-9f93-c19c7e84f01c&displaylang=en).

Here's a simple one:

```
IsFormula<br>
=ARGUMENT("aCell",8)<br>
=RETURN(GET.CELL(48, aCell))<br>
```

You can then use the macro in a formula, e.g. `=IsFormula(A1)`