# Excel VBA not working on Mac

Tags: excel, excel-2008, vba

I have written some code in Excel 2007 and tried to run it on a Mac with Excel 2008. The procedure is linked to a control button on the sheet, and there was a similar discussion going on here: [Excel vba to mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935028/excel-vba-to-mac)

However, in my case this does not seem to be the exact same problem. When I open the file on Mac, Excel recognises that a macro exists (it gives the option to open the file with macros disabled). When I click the control button to run the macro, Excel DOES recognise that this is not just a picture but an actual control button (main difference to the problem in the thread I posted above) and then tells me that the associated macro called 'Main' cannot be found.

Unfortunately I just read the issue with ActiveX vs. Form buttons (discussed in the thread I posted above) only now, and I do not have access to a Mac at the moment. Otherwise I would test whether that solves it; however from the thread above I understand that the problem presented itself in a different way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel 2008 doesn't support VBA. The 2004 and 2011 versions do though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#VBA_programming

[Mac Excel 2008: Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051682/mac-excel-2008-macros)

Comment: Thanks...I was aware that it worked in 2004 so I was silly enough to assume that MS would not have removed it in 2008, just to add it back in for the 2008 version. I understand the issue of timely release...but that is just embarassing for MS. Many thanks for your help!